# List of busiest files

Tags: linux, monitoring, top, open-files

I'm looking for a tool which will list open files sorted by amount of activity in the file. So `lsof` does not do the job (unless I'm overlooking a way to use `lsof`). Ideally, the tool should work like `top`, and one should be able to switch between specific activity for sorting: reads, writes, bytes, seeks per second. Preferably, it should be readily available in RHEL/CentOS/EPEL.

Does such a tool exist?

Comment: You could have a look at `filetop` from `bcc-tools`, which is only available with 7.6 RHEL release and clones. I think it does not provide exactly the features you are looking for. [This RHEL arcticle](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/introduction-ebpf-red-hat-enterprise-linux-7) might also be interesting.

Comment: An other tool, which would not answer the question but can still help is [iotop](https://manpages.debian.org/iotop/iotop.8): I/O per process. Good enough to immediately put on the top a `find` command running on a huge tree

Comment: I would like to suggest `atop`, which is usually readily available in software repositories. It is a top-like tool that can show disk utilization per process/thread, see https://www.atoptool.nl/. It doesn't show per-file utilization AFAIK though.

Comment: Thomas: bcc-tools' filetop does exactly what I need, thanks. However, in CentOS 7.6, I need to patch it to handle a bug: https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/issues/2119
It looks like RHEL/CentOS 7.7 will have that fixed.

Answer (score 1):

[Sysdig](https://sysdig.com/opensource/inspect/) is probably what you want, it's programmable in case it isn't. The [topfiles_bytes](https://github.com/draios/sysdig/blob/dev/userspace/sysdig/chisels/topfiles_bytes.lua) "chisel" (sysdig script) lists the most I/O-ed files.

Comment: Interesting. However, adding kernel modules is possible in the environment where I would like to use this.

Comment: Ok, I am pretty sure that such a tool does not exist. Lsof just looks at a snapshot of the open files, there is no readily available metric for file i/o. Kernel extensions are the only way.